# Jest Parameterize a mockImplementation

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I am mocking a module as below. I want to parameterize the value my mock Module returns and use it across all my tests rather than redefining it everytime i need. How can i achieve this ? Based on https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options i was unable to find how to do it.

```
jest.mock<
      typeof import('.../module')
    >('.../module', () => {
      const original = jest.requireActual<
        typeof import('.../module')
      >('.../module');
      return {
        ...original,
        callExternal: jest
          .fn()
          .mockImplementation(
            (
              iframe: WindowProxy,
              eventTarget: Window,
              id: string,
              action: { functionName: string },
            ) => {
              switch (action.functionName) {
                case 'action1':
                case 'action2':
                case 'action3':
                  return Promise.resolve({ value: returnValueToBeMocked });
                case 'action4':
                default: {
                  const errorMessage = `Unimplemented function;
                  logError(errorMessage);
                  return Promise.reject(errorMessage);
                }
              }
            },
          ),
      };
    });
```

How do i create a function and parameterize this

Ideally i would like something of this sort

```
const mockModule = (mockValue)=>{ jest.mock<...above mock>}
const mock1 = mockModule(value1)
const mock2 = mockModule(value2);

describe('Feature',() =>{
    it('check with mock1', ()=>{ ..... })
    it('check with mock2', ()=>{ ..... })
})
```

Not sure if this is possible